# multi-dimensional array of 2 types cpp

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

this question is on c++. How can I make an array that, in first row has strings and in second row has doubles? I think it should be void but its not working. Is there any other way? Cheers

Comment: "I think it should be void but its not working." What exactly is not working? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have different types in an array.  If you need to have two different types there are several ways you can do that

- You can use a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) like: `std::pair<std::string, double>`
- You can use a `struct` or `class` to wrap the differnt types together like:

  ```
  struct some_name
  {
      std::string string_name;
      double double_name;
  };
  ```
- You could use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)
- You could use 2 separate arrays one for the `std::sting` part and one for the `double` part
- C++11 and beyond also has `std::tuple` that is like `std::pair` but can be used for more than 2 types.

I would also suggest the use of a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you know the size of the array at compile time and a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if the array size will not be known until run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pair`, but you have to give the size of this array.. For example:

```
std::array<std::pair<std::string, double>, 3> dummy{{"string", 1.1}, {"foo", 2.2}, {"bar", 3.3}};
```

You can then access the elements using `first` and `second`:

```
dummy[0].first  // it is a string (string)
dummy[1].second // it is a double (2.2)
```

You can also create a `struct` and have an array of `struct`..

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of `std::pair` or your own defined struct/class. Or if you require searching consider using `std::map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

Sample Code: using Pair

```
vector <pair <string, double> > test;
test.push_back(make_pair("Age",15.6));
test.push_back(make_pair("Job",5));
cout << test[0].first<<" " << test[0].second;
```

using structure:

```
struct str_test{
string name;
double value;
};
str_test temp;
temp.name = "Some";
temp.value = 1.1;
vector<str_test>test;
test.push_back(temp);
cout << test[0].name <<" "<<test[0].value;
```